# Right speaker louder than left speaker at low volume

Tags: audio, logitech-speakers

I have a set of Logitech X-520 speakers. As I gradually turn the volume up from 0%, the right speaker comes in at 5% while the left speaker comes in at 10% and they sound even at about 20%. About 10% is the volume I would listen to music quietly, but it is clearly louder in the right speaker at this level. This is the case no matter what I connect them to or how.

So I bought a set of Logitech z623 speakers and they had the exact same problem. I returned them for another set and they had the same problem too.

So my question is: Does every set of PC speakers behave this way? If so, why?

Thanks

Comment: So all your three speaker sets have the same "problem". Did you consider checking 1) Your computer? 2) Your sound settings on the computer? 3) Your ears?

Comment: 1) 2) Yes. I have tested it with my computer, xbox and phone, and with different ways of plugging those things into the speakers. I can also plug various headphones into said devices and it sounds fine. 3) Yes, the right speaker (with the volume control on it) is definitely louder no matter how I arrange them.

Comment: It's certainly not a common issue. I've dealt with dozens of sets of speakers without seeing it.

Comment: Sounds to me (at equal volume on both sides) like a good reason not to buy Logitech speakers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a common issue, many Z623 owners are experiencing it. I had returned my first set because of it, and my second set also has it. It's even mentioned in reviews.

References:

- http://forums.logitech.com/t5/Speakers/Z623-Unbalanced-Audio/td-p/560478
- http://www.expertreviews.co.uk/pc-speakers/1281865/logitech-z623

Answer (score 0):

if you have a soundcard or some other sound feature, set the DB up for your one that's behind. Mine does the same thing. I have Klipsch ProMedias.